# Is Concurrency Control overridable

Tags: spring-security

I have in my applicationContext-security.xml

```
<session-management session-authentication-error-url="/genesis"> 
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/genesis?sessionExpired=true"/> 
    </session-management>
```

which limits a user to a single session. However, I now have a requirement that one account must be allowed multiple sessions whilst still limiting all other accounts to single session.

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override default concurrency filter. Skip processing for your special user:

```
public class CustomConcurrentSessionFilter extends ConcurrentSessionFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!auth.getName().equals("bob")) {
            super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
        }
    }

}
```

Replace default filter by custom one in conf:

```
<security:http ... >
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="customConcurrentSessionFilter"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="customConcurrentSessionFilter" class="com.domain.CustomConcurrentSessionFilter"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However reading the Javadoc for ConcurrentSessionFilter I'm concerned that by skipping the execution I'm going to miss out on everything else it does. From the API docs it looks like what I want to do is to override the getMaximumSessionsForThisUser() method in the ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy in a custom class and inject that into the ConcurrentSessionFilter. Any ideas on how I actually configure this?

Comment: Just override `getMaximumSessionsForThisUser()` in child class and add it as `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` (`"sas"`) bean and add `<session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />` and `<bean:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />` in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: +1 for overridnig getMaximumSessionsForThisUser() in CustomSessionAuthenticationStrategy

Comment: Xaerxess - forgive my dimness but could you give me an example (or point to a reference) on how to access/configure the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: See example here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions

Comment: Xaerxess - I've overridden the getMaximumSessionsForThisUser() and added to the config as you suggest. Now everything seems to work as required, why do I need to inject it onto the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter as well? Could you also put your solution as an answer so I can accept it please

Comment: I'm accepting the original answer just to clear it - but the solution that worked for me was the comment supplied by Xaerxess

Comment: @user497087 I posted and expanded my comment as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

*(I expand my comment here to provide more complete solution to this problem.)*

Just override `getMaximumSessionsForThisUser()` in `ConcurrentSessionFilter` child class (below I used `com.example.CustomConcurrentSessionFilter`) and in XML config add:

- `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` bean (with id `"sas"`),
- `<session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />` in `<http>`,
- `<bean:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />` to your `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

Complete setup should look similar to one shown [here in docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions):

```
<http>
  <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
  <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />

  <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/genesis"
      session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
   class="com.example.CustomConcurrentSessionFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/genesis?sessionExpired=true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter"
    class="o.s.s.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas"
    class="o.s.s.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
  <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
  <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="o.s.s.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```